# What do we know about the territory of the Goa'uld Empire and other SG civilizations?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

I am watching *SG-1* and just got to "Fair Game" which made me wonder, are there maps and or political information about the dominion of the Goa'ulds (and the other Civs) of *Stargate* that are canon?

A 10x speed that is quoted in the final episode of season 1; it doesn't seem like they could project their power far when you consider their civilization and the fact that Apophis who was considered a top Goa'uld was severely crippled by only having 2 ships destroyed.

It is constantly talked about how strong the Goa'uld are, but it seems like they are more like a 3rd world power with nuclear arms stomping on Hunter-Gatherer Tribes than a 1st world power to compare it to the real/modern world. So it makes me wonder how big and powerful they are, as well as the other civilizations the SGC run into territorilly.

---

The question is about the territory the that Goa'uld and other Civilizations, as in political border maps, or the scope/scale of the area they hold power in. The extra info is only important in that it is often these factors that determine how big a territory a nation can hold, for example, on Earth it is fairly standard that if you can't respond in 1 month's time, you cannot hold that territory.

When you look at their tech capabilities the Goa'uld should not be able to hold many worlds, but the Stargate changes this. So are there any known sources for how big the average goa'uld kingdom is, how many there are, and how much territory of the galaxy it covers?

Comment: "Third World power with nuclear arms" - how many of those can you name right now.

Comment: @HorusKol - North Korea

Comment: @HorusKol A few, depending on the definition of 3rd World. China for example is a 3rd world nation under some definitions and they have nuclear arms. I'm more using the term as what it brings to mind than any exact nation per se.

Comment: @HorusKol - depending on the exact definition you use. If you recall, [3rd World was originally a term denoting **alignment**](http://politics.stackexchange.com/a/611/115), not economic development level; so India and Pakistan are in the list.

Comment: Interesting - I was only taught the economic version... And the gist of the OP seems to be directed at tech level rather than alignment.

Comment: @valorum -supposedly  detonating a nuclear device and having a weapon are entirely separate. Then again, tech level in North Korea is not "third world", either

Comment: @HorusKol - They certainly aren't a "first world" country.

Comment: @Valorum: I'm not sure I can agree with that.

Comment: I agree they are a distorted economy - not sure they are third world, though.

Comment: I think the Goa'uld are only powerful by way of being parasites on other intelligent creatures. Their advanced technology comes from the intelligent creatures, though eventually some Goa'uld live long enough to gather enough information to create their own technology. Still, they don't develop as an intelligent civilization.
Ultimately, even though they're powerful, they're intellectually lazy, interested only in satisfying their own appetites, and happy with a feudal society. They also believe their own press, and have come to believe that they really are gods.

Answer (score 2):

Combined, the Goa'uld are extremely powerful. Indeed, they are the dominant race in the Milky Way. However, they are extremely territorial, and uncooperative.

This means that they run an almost feudal system - and are continually jockeying for supremacy. Apophis' loss of not only two ships, but also the elite forces he'd embarked on them, made him easy prey for his neighbors to start encroaching on his territory.

We see this throughout *SG-1* where newer Goa'uld fill the vacuum of vanquished Goa'uld.